# unable to create compute environment for salesforce functions

Tags: salesforce-functions

I have created Salesforce functions and run it locally . I am trying to create comput environment to deploy my function .But i am getting the below error.

```
Creating compute environment for org ID xxxxxxxxxxxxx... error!
 »   Error: Couldn't find that app.
 »
 »   Error ID: not_found
```

I have used sfdx:force:org list to find the alias name

```
sfdx force:org:list
```

=== Orgs
ALIAS            USERNAME                           ORG ID              CONNECTED STATUS
───  ───────────────  ─────────────────────────────────  ──────────────────  ────────────────
(X)  functionsdemoSO  xxxx@xxx.com  xxxx Connected

Then i have tried the below command in the target folder

```
sf login functions
sf env create compute -o functionsdemoSO -a functiondx
```

But I am getting the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello [@sfdcudhay](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/107369/sfdcudhay), make sure you have enabled the Production/Test Space under Setup > Functions in your org.

[image: Enable Production Space]

Comment: getting "NoUsernameFoundError: No username found."